# Convert consecutive qualifying values into hyphenated expressions in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, date, multidimensional-array, contiguous

I have the following example array

```
$workerHoliday = array
(
array("john","2018-12-24 1","2018-12-25 0","2018-12-26 0","2018-12-27 1","2018-12-28 ","2018-12-31 1"), // 12.29 and 12.30 are weekends
array("mark","2018-12-14 1","2018-12-17 1","2018-12-18 1"), // 12.15 and 12.16  are weekends .
array("ben","2018-11-05 1","2018-11-06 1","2018-11-12 1","2018-11-13 1")
);
```

This contains the workers name and a date where he has requested a vacation, marked with 1 .So "2018-12-24 1" means that he wants to be free on that day . "2018-12-25 0" The Zero means that , that day is a holiday , so the worker is usually free on that day . The weekends and the holidays should be filtered out. And if the main idea of the worker is , to be free from 12.24 to the 12.31 , we should get "2018-12-24 - 2018-12-31 1" .Also a worker can have multiple vacation requests in 1 array (look at ben). So at the end the array should look like this.

```
 $workerHoliday = array
  (
  array("john","2018-12-24 - 2018-12-31 1"), 
  array("mark","2018-12-14 - 2018-12-18 1"), 
  array("ben","2018-11-05 - 2018-11-06 1","2018-11-12 - 2018-11-13 1")
  );
```

Comment: And what have you tried to solve this problem? What errors did you get?

Comment: To be honest the original format is pretty weak, and so is the result you want.  What I mean by that is the data is not really in a usable format.  It's better to do it with keys like `['employee' => 'john', 'vacation' => [[ 'start'=>'2018-12-24', 'end'=>'2018-12-31'], [...]]]`,  Otherwise there is to much double handling of the data, it's too easy for bugs and errors to accumulate and have no way to resolve them.  Also your losing data such as how many actual vacation days are needed.  You could simply add another key in for that in `vacation` sub-arrays.